# Parts of my app only show when I'm resuming my app (onResume)

Tags: android, android-webview, onresume, activity-lifecycle

When my app starts initially, not on all devices but on different android versions + emulator, the webviews and my toolbar title will be just white (text is set properly and URL of webview is loaded properly). When I'm just resuming/closing the app (Don't close it entirely, just resuming) my app works fine. While debugging nothing useful was detected because everything seems to work normal as it should be.

One issue is the title of my toolbar. It gets set properly but won't show until I resume my app.

(toolBarTitle is "Community")

```
toolbar_title.text = toolBarTitle 
toolbar_title.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

My WebView doesn't show either until resuming

```
private fun initWebViews() {

    for (webView in webViewArray) {
        webView.settings.run {
            javaScriptEnabled = true
            domStorageEnabled = true
            allowFileAccess = true
            allowContentAccess = true
        }
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(JavaScriptBridge(this), "Android")

        (webView.parent as SwipeRefreshLayout).setOnRefreshListener {
            webView.clearCache(true)
            webView.loadUrl("about:blank")
            webView.reload()
            webView.loadUrl(webView.url)
        }

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                //super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                webView.tag = "started"

                webViewsInitialized += 1

                if (!NetworkHandler.hasActiveInternetConnection(applicationContext)) {
                    include_no_connection.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }

                if (view == getCurrentWebView()) {
                    showLoading()
                    url?.let { handleToolbarTitle(viewanimator_main.displayedChild, it) }
                }

                // desc: Wenn beim Logout die logoutpage aufgerufen wird dann den weiteren logout prozess initieren
                if (url!!.contains("logout.php")) {
                    isLoggedOut = true
                    initiateLogout()
                }
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String) {
                //super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                webView.tag = "finished"

                view?.scrollTo(0, 0)

                if (view == getCurrentWebView()) {
                    hideLoading()

                    (view.parent as SwipeRefreshLayout).isRefreshing = false

                    if (include_no_connection.visibility == View.VISIBLE && NetworkHandler.hasActiveInternetConnection(applicationContext)) {
                        include_no_connection.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }
                webView.evaluateJavascript(JS_CUSTOMER_ID_CHANGED) {}
                webView.evaluateJavascript(JS_NOTIFICATIONS) {}

                Log.d(TAG, "PageFinished " + view?.url);
            }



            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
                super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)

                val currentUrl = request?.url.toString()

                // desc: Externe Links werden im Browser geöffnet

                if (!currentUrl.contains(DTW)) {
                    view?.context?.startActivity(Intent(ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(currentUrl)))
                    return true
                }

                // desc: Wenn die angesteuerte url für einen anderen tab bestimmt ist wird diese umgeleitet
                val mappedResult = MappingUtil.mapTargetUrl(currentUrl, viewanimator_main.displayedChild)

                if (viewanimator_main.displayedChild != mappedResult && webView != webview_community && webViewArray[mappedResult].url != currentUrl) {
                    selectNavItem(mappedResult, false)
                    webViewArray[mappedResult].loadUrl(currentUrl)
                    showLoading()
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
        }
```

Comment: could be a race condition problem. Unless we see some code we won't be able to tell for sure!

Comment: I really dont know which part of my code is the issue. While debugging everything works totally fine so its really hard for me to tell which snippets could be usefull. But i try.

Comment: The toolbar issue could come from the Manifest.xml
Double check where you define the style for that activity and make sure it's not `NoActionBar`. Otherwise you will have to add the *Toolbar* in your layout.xml